# prove that: $ \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \sin \frac{1}{x-a} \mathrm{~d} x$ is convergent.

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

$g(x)$ is continous over$ (a, b]  $, $ g(x)(x-a)^{2}  $ is monotonic over $  (a, b]$ and $$  \lim _{x \rightarrow a^{+}} g(x)(x-a)^{2}=0 $$ prove that$$  \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \sin \frac{1}{x-a} \mathrm{~d} x$$ is convergent.

I try to construct $$ \int_{a}^{b} g(x) (x-a)^{2} \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x-a}}{(x-a)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x$$to satisfy Dirichlet‘s test but I don't know how to do next

Comment: Not an answer, just some ideas. I assume that $a,b>0$, otherwise my argument won't work. By limit, you can choose $\delta>0$ for which $|g(x)|<1/(x-a)^2$ for all $x\in (a,\delta+a)$. If $\delta$ is made sufficiently small so that $\delta+a<b$, then $g$ will become bounded on the interval $[\delta+a,b]$. So, if you split the integral in two parts and consider them seperately, they will converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so clear to proceed, so we change the variable. Let $u = 1/(x - a)$, then $u \to +\infty$ as $x \to a^+$, and the integral becomes
$$
\int_{+\infty}^{1/(b-a)} g(a + u^{-1})\sin(u) \mathrm d (a+u^{-1}) =:\int_{c}^{+\infty} \frac {g(a+u^{-1}) \sin (u)}{u^2} \mathrm du, 
$$
then note that
$$
u^{-2}g(a+u^{-1}) \searrow 0 \quad [u \to +\infty] 
$$ [WLOG we can assume the function decreases, otherwise we add a minus sign to $\sin (u)$]
and $\vert \sin(u) \vert $ has bounded integral over any compact interval in $(c, +\infty)$, thus the convergence follows from the Dirichlet test.